# Database Engine Tuning advisor "Performing analysis" fails with STOPPED

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, database-tuning-advisor

Whenever I run Database Engine Tuning advisor I get no recommendations (even when I set up scenarios with table scans that would be avoided by an index).

I see "Performing analysis" shows as "Stopped" with no errors or explanation. What is the cause of this and how do I correct?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The Tuning Log right below your results, will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I currently have the same problem and the tuning log right below doesn't contain any entries.

Comment: I have the same issue with SQLServer 2012  & SSMS 2017. Tuning advisor reports completed with success, but the entries for "Performing Analysis" and "Generating Reports" end with the status STOPPED. The Tuning Log pane is empty except for the column headers.

Comment: Has this ever been solved? I'm having the same issue now. I tried the suggestion below and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a SSMS/SQLServer versionin compatibility issue. 
I previously used SSMS2017 on the client against SQL2012 on the server.
Running my DTA from the sqlserver itself (where the versions match) I get a successful output.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this exact problem was to only select (under the General tab) the tables used in the select query.